# Android: Vertical line in Table view programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablelayout

I am developing an application in which i am generating rows programmatically as :

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
for(int j=0; j<50; j++){
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setText("Dynamic TV");
        t.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        t.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tableRow.addView(t);

        // Added Horizontal line as
        View view=new View(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));
        tableLayout.addView(view);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.1f));
}
```

In this i inserted horizontal line but my need is:

**1.** I want vertical line as a column seperater, and

**2.** Want to reduce height of horizontal line.

I tried various ways but not able to achive the task. Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add vertical separator and set the height 1px you can try this

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
TextView t = new TextView(this);
t.setText("Dynamic TV");
t.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
t.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableRow.addView(t);

// Add vertical separator
                View v = new View(this);
                v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));
                tableRow.addView(v);
            }
            // Added Horizontal line as
            View view = new View(this);
            view.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));
            tableLayout.addView(view);

tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
// Added Horizontal line as
    View view1=new View(this);
    view1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));
    tableLayout.addView(view1);
```